# Docker-compose port forwarding

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a website hosted on shared hosting on production. The website connects to the database via `localhost` in the code. In my docker-compose I have a `php:5.6-apache` and `mysql:5.6` instance.

Is there any way to tell docker-compose to have port 3306 on the web container port forwarded to 3306 on the db container, so that when the web container tries to connect to localhost on 3306 it gets sent to db on 3306 and also share port 80 on the web container to the outside world?

Current docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"

services:
  web:
    build:  .
    #image: php:5.6-apache
    ports:
     - "8080:80"
    environment:
     - "APP_LOG=php://stderr"
     - "LOG_LEVEL=debug"
    volumes:
     - .:/var/www/html
    network_mode: service:db # See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45458460/95195
#    networks:
#     - internal
    working_dir: /var/www
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6
    ports:
     - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - "MYSQL_XXXXX=*****"
    volumes:
      - ./provision/mysql/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
#    networks:
#     - internal

networks:
  internal:
    driver: bridge
```

Current error:

> ERROR: for web  Cannot create container for service web: conflicting options: port publishing and the container type network mode

Answer (score 15):

Yes it is possible. You need to use the `network_mode` option. See the below example

```
version: '2'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "3306:3306"
  app:
    image: ubuntu:16.04
    command: bash -c "apt update && apt install -y telnet && sleep 10 && telnet localhost 3306"
    network_mode: service:db
```

outputs

```
app_1  | Trying 127.0.0.1...
app_1  | Connected to localhost.
app_1  | Escape character is '^]'.
app_1  | Connection closed by foreign host.
```

`network_mode: service:db` instructs docker to not assign the `app` services it own private network. Instead let it join the network of `db` service. So any port mapping that you need to do, needs to happen on the `db` service itself.

The way I usually use it is different, I create a `base` service which runs a infinite loop and the `db` and `app` service both are launched on base service network. All ports mapping need to happen at the base service.

Comment: It seems that flag is incompatiable with ports. I want to do that but also have the web container port 80 be accessiable to the world. I'm having trouble understanding exactly how network_mode:service does from the docs.

Comment: Updated the answer with more details on port. See the upate