# Docker port redirection ignored on external network

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is an extension to the question [Docker-compose port forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45458052/docker-compose-port-forwarding) (and hopefully simpler).

I have a larger app that I've reduced down to this example consisting of just phpmyadmin:

```
version: '3'
services:
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    environment:
    - "PMA_ARBITRARY=1"
    ports:
    - "8080:80"
    networks:
      public_net:
        ipv4_address: 192.168.100.1
networks:
  public_net:
    external: true
```

I want make accessible via phpmyadmin on port 8080 on my "external" pre-configured network.  However, I don't get a warning.  The `ports` clause is silently ignored and phpmyadmin appears on port 80 on the ip 192.168.100.1.

**What is the proper way to redirect ports when an external network is being used?**

(This question has been further simplified.)

Comment: I’m pretty sure you can’t do this in the way you’re describing. In this setup, `ports:` has no effect, and I don’t think an external Compose network makes a difference either.  You’re manually setting the container-private IP address and whatever ports are being listened to be processes in that container will be reachable.

Comment: So as soon as I assign an IP address I can no longer control which port goes where?  My app includes a number of images which default to port 80 each time.  If I can't reassign them then they will conflict.